# How can I “fix” iPadOS Safari that is extremely slow in loading webpages?

Tags: ipad, ipados, mobile-safari

I got a new iPad from Apple to replace mine that got water damaged.  I restored from my backup and things have been mostly fine.  But Safari is killing me.  I can open bookmarks to sites like washingtonpost.com, cnn.com, but some sites like old.reddit.com hang or give me a slow blue loading line.

When I get fed up, I swipe up and close Safari, then click on the app in my dock and Safari loads the previously hung page just fine.

How can I “reset” Safari on this iPad without having to do a complete iPad reset?

Note: I have already tried **Settings and Clear History Website Data** and **Reset Network Settings**

I called AppleCare, and they’re practically useless.

ETA: I’ve been able to confirm that sites that hang often have popups, such as [this example](https://ifunny.co/video/duck-fallas-oh-look-it-s-AOuT3hWn8) which asks the user to use the browser or mobile app.

Comment: What iPad model and what OS version? That's not normal behaviour, so something seems weird. It's not your network speed? Safari is likely to used cached files when re-launching, which might explain why it's fast then. You don't have any custom profiles, extensions or other modifications?

Comment: iOS 16 and iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation), no extensions. I’ve noticed some of these slow sites often have some sort of notification like “You have messages”.

Comment: It’s definitely related to popups that try to load with the page